# How to design a pseudocode to detect if an non-directed graph has a C4 cycle with runtime O (| V³ |)

Tags: graph, graph-theory

This case is specific at runtime O (|V³|) and to find a C4 cycle. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail in your answer. You should also include the important details from the question title in the body of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find [all cycles in the graph](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GA/homeworks/hw1/Johnson%2075.PDF).
2. For each cycle:

   1. Generate a forest of edge distinct depth- (or breadth-) first search trees rooted from vertices on the cycle and terminating when it reaches any vertex on the cycle.
   2. The paths connecting points on the cycle are given by the roots and leaves of the DFS trees.
   3. If there exists two (vertex and edge distinct) paths, u<sub>1</sub>->v<sub>1</sub> and u<sub>2</sub>->v<sub>2</sub>, such that the vertices are ordered u<sub>1</sub> < u<sub>2</sub> < v<sub>1</sub> < v<sub>2</sub> around the cycle (in either direction) then the graph has a complete K<sub>4</sub> minor.

Johnson's algorithm to find elementary cycles is `O((v+e)(c+1))` for v vertices, e edges and c elementary cycles.

A DFS (or BFS) is `O(v+e)` so repeating it for each cycle is also `O((v+e)c)`.

You then need to order the paths and find distinct paths with alternating end-points (for each cycle) which may be possible in the complexity you require.